# Android, Java: HTTP POST Request

Tags: java, android, http-post

I have to do a http post request to a web-service for authenticating the user with username and password. The Web-service guy gave me following information to construct HTTP Post request.

```
POST /login/dologin HTTP/1.1
Host: webservice.companyname.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 48

id=username&num=password&remember=on&output=xml
```

The XML Response that i will be getting is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<login>
 <message><![CDATA[]]></message>
 <status><![CDATA[true]]></status>
 <Rlo><![CDATA[Username]]></Rlo>
 <Rsc><![CDATA[9L99PK1KGKSkfMbcsxvkF0S0UoldJ0SU]]></Rsc>
 <Rm><![CDATA[b59031b85bb127661105765722cd3531==AO1YjN5QDM5ITM]]></Rm>
 <Rl><![CDATA[username@company.com]]></Rl>
 <uid><![CDATA[3539145]]></uid>
 <Rmu><![CDATA[f8e8917f7964d4cc7c4c4226f060e3ea]]></Rmu>
</login>
```

This is what i am doing    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlString); How do i construct the rest of the parameters?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Here's an example previously found at [androidsnippets.com](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) (the site is currently not maintained anymore).

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

So, you can add your parameters as [`BasicNameValuePair`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html).

An alternative is to use `(Http)URLConnection`. See also [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests). This is actually the preferred method in newer Android versions (Gingerbread+). See also [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html), [this developer doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) and Android's [`HttpURLConnection` javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: Is there an easy way to add arrays? Would you have to loop through them and add the pair BasicNameValuePair("array[]",array[i])?

Comment: Is it also effective on JSON files instead in XML?

Comment: For Android 2.3 and higher Google recommends use HttpURLConnection. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge: Fortunately, I copypasted the extract of relevance in the answer instead of keeping it to a link-only answer.

Answer (score 6):

to @BalusC answer I would add how to convert the response in a String:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

    String result = RestClient.convertStreamToString(instream);
    Log.i("Read from server", result);
}
```

[Here is an example of convertStramToString](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/12145).

Answer (score 5):

Please consider using HttpPost. Adopt from this: http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip34.html

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://webservice.companyname.com/login/dologin").openConnection();
// Http Method becomes POST
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// Encode according to application/x-www-form-urlencoded specification
String content =
    "id=" + URLEncoder.encode ("username") +
    "&num=" + URLEncoder.encode ("password") +
    "&remember=" + URLEncoder.encode ("on") +
    "&output=" + URLEncoder.encode ("xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

// Try this should be the length of you content.
// it is not neccessary equal to 48. 
// content.getBytes().length is not neccessarily equal to content.length() if the String contains non ASCII characters.
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", content.getBytes().length); 

// Write body
OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream(); 
output.write(content.getBytes());
output.close();
```

You will need to catch the exception yourself.

Comment: How do i print the response?

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather recommend you to use **Volley** to make **GET, PUT, POST...** requests.

First, add dependency in your gradle file.

`compile 'com.he5ed.lib:volley:android-cts-5.1_r4'`

Now, use this code snippet to make requests.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest( com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, mURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //add your parameters here as key-value pairs
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpClient for Java:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: Did you miss the `Android` tag? It's already using (a lite version of) HttpClient under the covers! See also the [HttpPost javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the implementation I added to ACRA:
http://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/tags/REL-3_1_0/CrashReport/src/org/acra/HttpUtils.java?r=236

(See the doPost(Map, Url) method, working over http and https even with self signed certs)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to send HTTP POST from my android client app to C# desktop app on my server:

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

I worked on reading the request from a C# app on my server (something like a web server little application).
I managed to read request posted data using the following code:

```
server = new HttpListener();
server.Prefixes.Add("http://*:50000/");
server.Start();

HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
HttpListenerContext context = obj as HttpListenerContext;
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);
string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score -1):

**HTTP request POST in java does not dump the answer?**

```
public class HttpClientExample 
{
 private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
 {

HttpClientExample http = new HttpClientExample();

System.out.println("\nTesting 1 - Send Http POST request");
http.sendPost();

}

 // HTTP POST request
 private void sendPost() throws Exception {
 String url = "http://www.wmtechnology.org/Consultar-RUC/index.jsp";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

// add header
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accion", "busqueda"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("modo", "1"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nruc", "10469415177"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
System.out.println("Response Code : " +response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  String line = "";
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
        {
      result.append(line);
                System.out.println(line);
    }

   }
 }
```

**This is the web: http://www.wmtechnology.org/Consultar-RUC/index.jsp,from you can consult Ruc without captcha. Your opinions are welcome!**

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer so OP can extract value out of it :)