# Adding post parameters to request before making the request go somewhere else in Java

Tags: java, http, jsp, post

In a JSP page, I need to do the following (this is psuedo-code):

```
//Attach new POST params to request
//Make the request go to a 3rd party URL
```

How do I do this?

The way we are solving this right now (is terrible):

```
//populate and generate an HTML form
//on window.load submit the HTML form (as a POST) to a 3rd party URL
```

We want all this to be done on the server side instead of having this JS hack

Comment: You may want to re-title this. A redirect is *very* different from forwarding a request. Redirecting implies a specific response code from the server and the client sees that and re-issues the request to the new URL. Forwarding on behalf of the client, especially to an entirely different domain, is a different beast.

Comment: OK. Thanks, I'll make it technically agnostic since I don't really know what the technical thing I want to do is called. I just care about what actually happens and don't want people to get hung up on terminology.

Comment: Note that the both answers are suggesting a server side approach of proxying the request (the URL in browser address bar points to your own site) while your initial solution does basically a client side submit (the URL in browser address bar will point to the 3rd party URL). Proxying might not be what you want at all.

Comment: You are correct, I don't really want proxying. I would prefer the user ended up at the 3rd party URL, I just want to be able to add a couple post vars on their way out, but the post vars have to be generated by a page that needs the info they place on the page they are leaving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Java. You would need some sort of proxy server or apache re-write rule or something like that. Java is not the right place to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to make `POST` request, [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html) is an example

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to send a HTTP POST. I recommend a use of apache `HttpClient` library.

Here is the previous [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request) on Stack Overflow. The question was for Andriod but should work perfectly with Java.

Another method is to use `URLConnection` class. There was an answer posted by me on that question.