# Is it possible to create forms as part on an Android application that connect to my server?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am building an application for Android, I want to keep it an Android application as much as possible, but it must connect to my database, for user registration, user login, file uploads etc.. I want to create these forms as Android views, with code behind that connects to the database on-line, I don't want to just create web pages that is not an Android application.

I have been researching this all day and experimenting with the Android SDK, but so far I cannot see that this is possible. I have a database built using PHP and MySQL, I have the functions built using HTML, I just need to figure out how to integrate all these forms into an Android application. Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you need the ADK for in this mix since that's used for connecting your android device to a Arduino microcontroller.

However, connecting to the MySQL database is as easy as sending a HTTP request of some sort, most usually a POST request.

Here's a link: [Android, Java: HTTP POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request)

Comment: Thanks for the link I am looking at the information just now.

Comment: Hope you find a solution (didn't want to paste a whole code snippet here when there are other snippets already available)

Comment: I was able to use HTTP POST and get it to connect to a database, but I eventually gave up with my project because building a log in form was too advanced for me, it is just the time, I am under a lot of pressure and don't have time to spare. I had great ambitions for this project!

I appreciate your help!