# Quote request program that emails information entered by user

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` that has various `EditText` boxes and `Spinners` that the user will fill out in order to receive a quote. This application will be used by our outside sales team and the information will be emailed to our inside team to process the quote. What is the best way to capture the information from this `Activity` and email it?

The way I was going to do this was when the *Process* `Button` was clicked, it would take the data entered and just automatically populate that text in the email field. Is this the best way or should I look into forms?

Also I have considered adding a feature that requires certain fields to have information and if they do not, you will not be able to proceed to submit the quote. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Lastly, One of the textboxes require the outside salesperson to enter a "quote due by" date. Is it possible to use a calendar feature to do this so when you click *Process* and the quote is sent to the inside team, it will be added to a calender or something that can be viewed by both parties to help keep track of pending quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't email through the app; instead, I would take all their data, send it in a POST request to a PHP server, and then handle it from there. You could either save it in a database your sales reps can access or immediately email the data to them through there. This way you can avoid all the nasty email authentication you'd have to do to keep it in-app, and this way you also don't need to pass the data to an email intent and have them manually send it.

Here's a good SO answer on using HttpPost requests within Android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544026/1426565