# Make POST request on Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know this has been asked before but I'm struggling.. I barely know any Java, but want an app so I can do my POST request without opening my website.

So I've got this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Address:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Phone:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="Comments:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="Done"
        android:onClick="goToWeb(???);" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this Java:

```
package com.example.request;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainRequest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_request);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_request, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void goToWeb() {
        /* open webpage - how? */
    }
}
```

I want to make this POST request to `http://www.example.com` when they click Done:

```
name: (content of @+id/editText1)
addr: (content of @+id/editText2)
phone: (content of @+id/editText3)
comment: (content of @+id/editText4)
```

I want the phone's browser to open, and perform the POST request (if that makes sense)

How do I do this?

Comment: Whoever's sending me `name: h, phone: 3, addr: j, comment: a` it's working :)

Comment: And I just got `name: a, phone: 2, addr: a, comment: j` and `name: a, phone: 2, addr: a, comment: d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this Class MainRequest

```
package com.example.teststack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainRequest extends Activity {

    EditText textPersonName = null;
    EditText textPostalAddress = null;
    EditText phone = null;
    EditText textMultiLine = null;
    Button submit = null;
    String action = "http://www.omokoroacomputerhelp.com/";
    HttpPost httpRequest = null;
    List<NameValuePair> params = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_request);
        textPersonName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personName);
        textPostalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postalAddress);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        textMultiLine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.multiLine);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                httpRequest = new HttpPost(action);
                params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", textPersonName
                        .getText().toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone.getText()
                        .toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addr", textPostalAddress
                        .getText().toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", textMultiLine
                        .getText().toString()));
                try {
                    // send http request
                    httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,
                            HTTP.UTF_8));
                    // get http response
                    httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest);
                    //
                    Intent gotoIntent = new Intent(MainRequest.this,
                            Webpage.class);
                    gotoIntent.putExtra("source",
                            EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
                    startActivity(gotoIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_request, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and Webpage

```
package com.example.teststack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Webpage extends Activity {
    WebView webView;

    final String mimeType = "text/html";

    final String encoding = "utf-8";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webpage);
        Intent webPageIntent = getIntent();
        String htmlSource = webPageIntent.getStringExtra("source");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadData(htmlSource, mimeType, encoding);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_webpage, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and activity_main_request.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/personName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/postalAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/personName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/personName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/postalAddress"
        android:text="Address:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postalAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postalAddress"
        android:text="Phone:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/multiLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/multiLine"
        android:text="Comments:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/multiLine"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/multiLine"
        android:text="Done" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and activity_webpage.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.teststack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainRequest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Webpage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_webpage" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one error I'm getting: `activity_webpage cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: You should add activity_webpage.xml in your project like /res/layout 
also add the follow text in your AndroidManifest.xml
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
`<activity
            android:name=".Webpage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_webpage" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: Refresh your project. press `F5` on your project. If this doesn't work, then rebuild the project `Project-->clean`

Comment: I commented out the offending code and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is a relevant question with a good answer that you may want to consider looking at. Hope this helps.

[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

EDIT: Actually I found an ever better one for Android specifically:

[Android, Java: HTTP POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request)

Okay so I guess you're also kinda confused about how to get the text from your text fields you created. Here is another stackoverflow question that can help you:

[Get Value of a Edit Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

You have some edittext fields set up so you just have to store them in a variable (you can get that value by using `findViewById(R.id.idOfEditText)` and storing it in a variable. Now with that variable, you just need to call `.getText()` and then you have the String and can do whatever you need to do with it (such as sending it via POST).

Comment: Sorry but I'm still struggling, how do I get the values from the text fields and POST them?

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry to just point you to other questions but if I feel there is another question that is asking what you need, then it's good (they generally explain it better than me XD) but if you still need help don't be afraid to ask

Comment: I've used the HTTP POST Request one (without yet trying to get the text boxes' data) and get a FC when I click done..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `NameValuePair`.. I am giving the code which i used in my app to do Http Post

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {



        final String urlStr = url;
        final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
        final StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();


        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                HttpClient httpclient = MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);


                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                    Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String s = null;


                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.d("YumZing", s);
                        sb.append(s);
                    }


                    Log.d("Check Now",sb+"");




                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method "+sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```