# Creating correct HTTP POST data

Tags: java, android, http, post

Im new at android development and now I need to create and use POST request. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request/4544026#4544026)
I have tried to put my data:

```
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(13);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SelectedCode", "25"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone", "1234567"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Text", "1234"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IsTranslit", "false"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IsShedule", "false"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastDate", ""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastDateHour", "00"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastDateMinuts", "00"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DateSendBefore", ""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DateSendBeforeHour", "00"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DateSendBeforeMinuts", "00"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CaptchaDeText", "h3Vcjwk2moLagspo7lnKpg%3D%3D"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CaptchaInputText", "4myin2"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

but **it doesnt work**. Then I have tried to use this code (sorry for a long line)

```
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("SelectedCode=25&Phone=1234567&Text=123&IsTranslit=false&IsShedule=false&LastDate=&LastDateHour=00&LastDateMinuts=00&DateSendBefore=&DateSendBeforeHour=00&DateSendBeforeMinuts=00&CaptchaDeText=h3Vcjwk2moLagspo7lnKpg%3D%3D&CaptchaInputText=4myin2"));
```

And **it works**.
Can someone explain what is difference or what Im doing wrong?

**UPDATED:**

By doesnt work I mean that server does not recognize this post request as correct. It will happen if I add incorrect value in NameValuePair list for example. But from my side name and value in first piece of code and in the second are the same. It makes me wonder.

Comment: Doesnt work is not an error. What happens, what gets sent, what does the server receive?

Comment: If I remember well, `UrlEncodedFormEntity` encodes each parameter, but your `h3Vcjwk2moLagspo7lnKpg%3D%3D` parameter is already encoded. This could be a problem

Comment: hmm, yes, you was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vmirionov's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530895/creating-correct-http-post-data#comment-22001181) solved this issue. Changing `h3Vcjwk2moLagspo7lnKpg%3D%3D` to `h3Vcjwk2moLagspo7lnKpg==` made a trick.