# How to make HTTP Post request and get the response as JSON Android

Tags: android

I am new to android. In my application i want to send three parameters to HTTP (post) after that i will get JSON as response. how to make a call to HTTP and how i get the JSON data?  please help me.

thank you in advance

Comment: there are lots of examples just google it http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a nice tutorial on what you are looking for

http://www.itworld.com/article/2702452/development/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-google-volley-on-android.html

Comment: without google volley?

Comment: its best to use volley... optimized an managed does most of the dirty work of creating threads and managing them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request. i followed this link.,,but my response is not a json

Comment: volley also supports custom responses... i can give you other easy and dirty solution... but in my experience volley is amazing

Comment: thank you. After cleaned my project i missed my R.Java. how can i generate R.java file.