# Advice/Tips on creating an online database for a C# Windows Form and Android App

Tags: c#, android, mysql, database, cloud

I just wonder if anyone could help me about creating an online mysql database.

I've tried looking in the internet for tutorials but I am having problem with the topics because it is a bit advance for a beginner like me.

So I am trying to develop a Sales And Inventory Management System using C# windows forms and an Android App that will be able to monitor the inventory and transactions. They will both share the same database which I think that is called a Cloud Storage (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

So if anyone could give me advice or useful links on where to start the project and how to create an online mysql database will be a big help.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a SQL database, and Apache server which could run on a cloud computing platform such as Amazon Web Services, or Digital Oceans https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial. This could then be accessed via GET and POST requests from both the Android app, and the C# windows form, [Android, Java: HTTP POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request), [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post). Hope this helps.