# Android cannot communicate with localdjango server?

Tags: android, django, post, server, local

I am trying to post data from my client android application to a django server.
for example I have User {login:---, email:---} and I wanna post them my LOCAL SERVER based on django.. what I should do ? any link or tutorial can be greatful, i can't find any thing really helpful.Thks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a HTTP request to your django server. Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request) how to do a post request in android