# Android How to Send Post Request Without Third Party

Tags: android, post

I'm new in Android Developer, I have a project to create a library for Android, inside the library, I must send a post request to web service.

My questions are:

- is that possible to create a request for web service without using the third party?
- if that's possible how it has done? **Please give me an example**

I know there is a good and simple way if I using the third party such like a retrofit, but I don't want using the third party because I want to make my code secure and I want to learn

How do I archive this?

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you all can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean using android framework or java built-in ways, maybe [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection)

this is an [example](https://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android) and [an useful ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543894/android-java-http-post-request)

Comment: This solution what im looking for, Thank you sir